# SonarQube - DevOpsPlatformIntegration - Settings via curl

Tags: sonarqube

I want to use a curl command to modify the SonarQube settings done on the dashboard with steps **Project-Settings > DevOps-Platform-Integration > Configuration-Name & Repository-Name** to be able to locate these 2 actions inside of a script. Although I have achieved to use of quality-gates and quality-profile related activities with curl, I could not find an API URL for this part to be able to use curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it seems the curl below works as I request

> curl -u $token: -X POST -d "almSetting=XYZ" -d
> "repository=https://git.XYZ.com/XYZ/XYZ" -d "monorepo=false" -d
> "project=XYZ"
> "https://sonarqube.XYZ.com/api/alm_settings/set_github_binding"

Answer (score 1):

curl -u $token: -X POST -d "almSetting=configuration name" -d "repository=projectname" -d "monorepo=false" -d "project=project name in sonarqube" "https://sonarqube.XYZ.com/api/alm_settings/set_github_binding"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).